# Create a pandas dataframe from isnull().sum()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas
company_avg = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wbconnelly/Bill_Data_Sci/master/project%20draft/company_avg')

null_count = pd.DataFrame(company_avg.isnull().sum())
```

This returns a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Unnamed: 0_x                                    0
accountingchange                              484
amended                                         0
audited                                         0
capitalexpenditures                            18
```

The problem is I can't stop it from setting the first column as this index.  I want to create a DataFrame looking like this:

```
Index   Column                                      Count
    1    Unnamed: 0_x                                    0
    2    accountingchange                              484
    3    amended                                         0
    5    audited                                         0
    6    capitalexpenditures                            18
```

I can't seem to where the shape is 2 columns and seventy rows.  I have tried running null_count['Count'] = null_count[0] but it won't display the renamed column. It still appears with no title.  And no matter what I do I can't remove the column titles as the index.

Comment: It' because you passed a series as the data to DataFrame ctor, you can either call `reset_index()` on the df, or do something like `result = company_avg.isnull().sum() df = pd.DataFrame(data=[result.index, result.values])`

Comment: Because you passed the series, it's taken the index of the series as the index values and the data as the single column